# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare example() (previously declared

Tags: php

I' am using XAMPP and I' am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare example() (previously declared in
```

I understand about this error, It means that the function has been declared somewhere else.

In my **www.example.com/cores/functions.php** I' am declaring this function

```
function example(){
    $site_name = "Example CMS";
    return $site_name;
}
```

What this function will do, it will hold the default **Example CMS**. But if someone declares the same function in **www.example.com/functions.php**, then the system should pickup this which is in **www.example.com/functions.php** and should not pick in **www.example.com/cores/functions.php**

In my **www.example.com/functions.php**

```
function example(){
    $site_name = "My CMS";
    return $site_name;
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but only if you include the www.example.com/functions.php first.  Then in your cores/functions.php do this:

```
if (!function_exists('example')) {
  function example(){
    $site_name = "Example CMS";
    return $site_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `(previously declared ...` part of the error message, it means
you try to create a function which is already a built-in function.